# Elegant way to find indexes for lists within lists?

Tags: python-3.x, list, csv, for-loop

Pretty new to python.  I'm trying to index items in CSV files by row/column. The only method I've found is implementing a for loop to search each row in the list.

```
readCSV = [['', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
          [1.0, 3.1, 5.0, 1.7, 8.2],
          [2.0, 6.2, 7.0, 2.2, 9.3],
          [3.0, 8.8, 5.5, 4.4, 6.0]]

row_column = []
for row in readCSV:
    if my_item in row:
        row_column.append(row[0])
        row_column.append(readCSV[0][row.index(my_item)])
```

So for `my_item = 6.2`, I get `row_column = [2.0, 'A']`.

This works fine, but I can't help thinking there's a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
result = [(i, j) for i, k in enumerate(readCSV) for j, n in enumerate(k) if my_item == n]
```

Comment: This ended up being quite useful for me.  I was trying to make something like this work with the enumerate  statements, so this bit of code was what I was looking for.  After implementing this and playing with my code a little, I think I have a much clearer understanding of how enumerate and lists work.

Comment: Aha.  This shows I'm new to both stack overflow AND python.

Comment: It's totally fine! Good luck with Python! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(readCSV[1:],columns=readCSV[0])
#### Output ####
    No    A    B    C    D
0  1.0  3.1  5.0  1.7  8.2
1  2.0  6.2  7.0  2.2  9.3
2  3.0  8.8  5.5  4.4  6.0


##This provides the row in which there is a hit.
df1 = df[(df.A == my_item) | (df.B == my_item) |(df.C == my_item) | (df.D == my_item)]
print(df1)

#### Output ####
    No    A    B    C    D
1  2.0  6.2  7.0  2.2  9.3


##If you want only those column values which is a hit for your my_item.
z1 = pd.concat([df[df['A'] == my_item][['No','A']],df[df['B'] == my_item][['No','B']],df[df['C'] == my_item][['No','C']],df[df['D'] == my_item][['No','D']]])
print(z1)

#### Output ####
     A   B   C   D   No
1  6.2 NaN NaN NaN  2.0


## Incase if you want drop the nan , you can use np.isnan
z1 = np.array(z1)
print(z1[:,~np.any(np.isnan(z1), axis=0)])

#### Output ####
[[6.2 2. ]]
```

Comment: Numpy is probably the best way to handle extensive CSV use, for sure.